# `chmod 770 folderName` restrics access to subdirectories & subfiles?

Tags: permissions, directory

If I run `chmod 770 ./folderName`, then users who are not the owner or in the group owning `./folderName` (i.e. users in the “others” category) cannot access `./folderName/folderB` or `./folderName/fileC`, even after running:

```
chmod 777 ./folderName/folderB 
chmod 777 ./folderName/fileC
```

Right? Does that rule applies to all Linux distributions? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's correct. Removing execute permission will prevent access to the directory and all subdirectories, even if subdirectories are more permissive.

This will probably hold true for anything Unix like (and it may even be a POSIX requirement).

Comment: IIRC, then yes, it is both in SUS and POSIX.

Comment: To be precise, they now can't go through folderName (no x permission) to get at the file. They also can't list its contents (no r) nor delete the file, rename stuff or create new files (no w).